# Copying sqlite3 database to user folder and loading the database causes the app can not launch during WACK verification

Tags: c#, uwp

My app copy a sqlite3 database to user folder when users first time run the app

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using SQLitePCL;

//....

public sealed partial class MainPage  
{


    SQLiteConnection db;

    private void onLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded();//remove this line
    }

    public async void createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded()
    {
        StorageFolder aFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);

        if (await aFolder.TryGetItemAsync("app.data") != null)
        {
            db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "app.data"));
        }
        else  
        {
            var afile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/app.data"));

            if (afile != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(await afile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "app.data") != null)
                    {
                        db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "app.data"));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on my PC, but if I use WACK to verify, it reports can not launch app.

If I remove the line

```
createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded();
```

the app can pass WACK and launch, but it can not work correctly (database does not open).

later, I found that

```
if(await afile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "app.data") != null)
```

cause app can not launch, even I change 'app.data' to a small size png file, it still does not work, this means that the function

**CopyAsync** causes the app can not launch in WACK

```
-------------------------------------------------WACK error report
failed Platform version launch
Cannot launch App
The app  failed platform version launch test.
failed  App launch
Cannot launch App
failed Crashes and hangs
Executable myapp.exe was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
Application  was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
Crash dump file myapp.exe.1016.dmp was created by Windows Error Reporting and provides additional information.
Crash dump file myapp.exe.12440.dmp was created by Windows Error Reporting and provides additional information.

----------------------------------------------
```

Your comments are welcome

Comment: Can the app.data be found in the Assets folder? If you try to connect to the path of the app.data file in the Assets folder directly, can it pass WACK? In addition, can you show more detailed error messages from WACK test?

Comment: @ Faywang - MSFT  I found the await afile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "app.data") cause this happen

Comment: If you try to use `afile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "app.data",NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)` method, can it work? Or trying to copy a simple txt file.

Comment: I try both, same error result, but all of them work well on my pc

Comment: It looks like realated to file size. If I split the file(app.data) to 4100KB, rebuild file can pass WACK test, but my database file is about 5000KB, even I compact the database to a small size(4300KB), it is still larger than the worked file size(4100KB)

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?